# How to change the text of a menu?

Tags: android, text, menu, title

How do I change the text of a Menu in Android? I want to change the text that says "Welcome to Engineering", which is the name of the app, not the name of the list currently inflated.

[Here is a picture of the Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reURD.png)

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.bignerdranch.android.welcometoengineering">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".CourseListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.bignerdranch.android.welcometoengineering.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/files"/>
        </provider>
        <!--Hierarchies-->

        <activity
            android:name=".CoursePagerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".CourseListActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SemesterListActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".CourseListActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfessorListActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".SemesterListActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PostPagerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProfessorListActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the layout XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Layer 1 -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/semester_recycler_view"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the Menu for that layout file:

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

(I know the menu currently doesn't do anything. I'll change that soon.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add in your onCreate

```
this.setTitle("Your String");
```

Comment: Where would I put the getter/setter? The "Welcome to Engineering" is never explicitly set anywhere except the Manifest.

Comment: in that case on your toolbar reference toolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: or you can add this in your app theme for all activities. <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Sorry, but the toolbar method isn't working, as this isn't a toolbar, it's a menu. I'll try the app theme way and get back to you.